# Basic cluster computing and data management with Ray

Tags: python, cluster-computing, ray

I'm trying to use **Ray** to run parallel scientific simulations on distinct computers. I want to be able to change a parameter in a simulation and run many different versions of the same case to check its impact.

The tutorials and examples are working smoothly with **Ray**. However, I'm struggling to get things working for my case:

- I need to have a template file copied with the changed parameter. I can have the original file copied with `file_mounts` in the yaml file.  However, I can't find a way to change the working directory, except by `os.chdir` in the python file. When starting the cluster with ray start, the working dir is where I am, but with the yaml file, it's at each node's home.
- I'd like to be able to change the number of cpu with the yaml file, just like

  ```
  ray start --num-cpu=
  ```

However, I can't find a way to do it.

If you could provide a simple, basic case for my needs, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the YAML file, one workaround is to include `echo "cd WORKING_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc` in the setup_commands.
2. You can specify the ray start commands by using the `example-full.yaml` template here: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/autoscaler/aws/example-full.yaml

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I didn't notice that start command could be used and I should have.